# Spaceless does not want to work correctly in Symfony2 Twig Template

Tags: php, symfony

I expected the following:

```
{% spaceless %}
    blablabla
        blablabla
            blablabla
        blablabla
    blablabla
{% endspaceless %}
```

to return the following string:

`blablabla blablabla blablabla blablabla blablabla`

but in the page source, I see this:

```
    blablabla
        blablabla
            blablabla
        blablabla
    blablabla
```

How to do this without any HTML `<tags>`?

Answer (score 9):

You can achieve this by using a [whitespace control modifier](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/templates.html#whitespace-control) in a twig comment:

```
{#-  #}blablabla {# -#}
    blablabla {# -#}
            blablabla {# -#}
    blablabla {# -#}
blablabla{# -#}
```

a 'regular' comment looks like this: {# my comment #}

adding a '-' will remove the whitespaces before or after the comment (or both):

- remove whitespaces before comment: {#- my comment #}
- remove whitespaces after comment: {# my comment -#}
- remove whitespaces before and after: {#- my comment -#}

by the way, this also works for {{- ... -}} and {%- ... -%}

Answer (score 6):

As explained in the [documentation](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/spaceless.html), "Use the spaceless tag to remove whitespace between HTML tags, **NOT** whitespace within HTML tags or whitespace in plain text:"

```
{% spaceless %}
    <div>blablabla</div>
        <div>blablabla</div>
            <div>blablabla</div>
        <div>blablabla</div>
    <div>blablabla</div>
{% endspaceless %}
```

Will output:

```
<div>blablabla</div><div>blablabla</div><div>blablabla</div><div>blablabla</div><div>blablabla</div>
```

Comment: But how to make spaceless without tags?

Comment: What is your use case?

Comment: Just I want get Blablabla blablabla without divs :P

Comment: @user3766478 what if you wrap it in <span> tags?

Comment: Thanks @COil, I glossed over that detail in the docs, and your highlighting/emphasis here helped me figure things out. FWIW, my personal use case was `<span>item1</span>, <span>item2</span>,` etc., and my commas were coming out w/ spaces before them, so I guess I'll have to wrap them in spans too.